# Retrieve data based on hierarchical references

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data

I have one table in which data is stored in hierarchical manner. In below table, we have parent for each child.

| CHILD_ID | PARENT_ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 6 |
| 10 | 8 |
| 11 | 5 |
| 12 | 7 |
| 13 | 4 |

I have another table where we have interest of each child. Example as below

| CHILD_ID | INTEREST |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | SPORTS |
| 11 | BOOKS |
| 7 | POLITICS |
| 12 | SPORTS |
| 7 | BOOKS |
| 8 | TV |
| 12 | POLITICS |

Using a SQL query in Oracle, I want to retrieve count of interests under the hierarchy of ID as 2, i.e. it should consider 2 and its direct or grand children, i.e 4, 7, 12 & 13.

Output of the query should be 4.

Note: I tried to use connect_by_root but not successful in query creation.

Comment: Oracle supports two forms of a hierarchical query. What have you tried so far?

Comment: 6, 8, and 10 are not descendants of ID 2.

Comment: The question doesn't make sense as asked. Voting to close.

Comment: Sorry. Somehow i mixed up numbers while typing. I have edited question now.

Comment: @Serg - Please share if any inputs/suggestions on this

Comment: @TheImpaler -  Please share if any inputs/suggestions on this

Answer (score 0):

Using an ancient `connect by`

```
with bom as (
   select distinct connect_by_root(parent_id) root, child_id
   from data
   start with parent_id = 2
   connect by prior child_id = parent_id
)
select b.root, count(distinct interest) ni
from bom b
join interests s on s.child_id in (b.root, b.child_id)
group by b.root
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d0f6f615da10e67eddbe411a524b4021)